# Hacking a Google Home device to put a "hard switch" on its microphone

Tags: hardware, google-home

It's my understanding that Google Home devices all have a soft switch for their microphone; i.e. no physical circuit is broken when you turn it "off".

Is it particularly difficult to open it up and maybe add a bit of wiring to convert it to a hard switch?

Answer (score 6):

Google home devices have many microphones, used for "beam shaping" (listening to the best mic), and noise-cancellation. This means you'd need a multi-channel mux, or several independent switches. Also, these mics tend to be surface-mount, so there's no wire you can intercept, making it very tough to modify without proper tools (stereo microscope, reflow oven, etc).

I think you're better off unplugging the power and waiting for it to boot.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  What I was *really* hoping to do was find an easy way to make the stupid things a bit more secure whether or not the device is "listening" is currently just a function of how honest the software is.  Essentially, the equivalent of putting a bit of masking tape over your laptop camera.

Comment: the only work-around i can think of would be to add earbud drivers pointing at the mics to "drown out" ambient sound using pink noise or a reversed podcast (talking) loop when needed.